# Pandas data frame: replace nan with the mean of that row

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Assume I've the following data frame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [np.nan, 1,2], 
                                  'B' : [3, np.nan, 4], 
                                  'C': [5,6,np.nan]}).T

>>df
    0   1   2
A NaN   1   2
B   3 NaN   4
C   5   6 NaN
```

To replace `np.nan` with the mean of the row in which the `np.nan` occurred, I used the [fillna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method as follows:

```
fill_value = pd.DataFrame({col: df.mean(axis=1) for col in df.columns})
df.fillna(fill_value, inplace=True)

Yields:
     0    1    2
A  1.5  1.0  2.0
B  3.0  3.5  4.0
C  5.0  6.0  5.5
```

I am not sure why I can’t get [filled](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.MaskedArray.filled.html) method to do the same thing:

```
mask = np.isnan(df)
masked_df = np.ma.masked_array(df, mask)
means = np.mean(masked_df, axis=0)
df = masked_df.filled(means)

Yields: 
array([[ 4. ,  1. ,  2. ],
       [ 3. ,  3.5,  4. ],
       [ 5. ,  6. ,  3. ]])
```

Any idea how I can get `filled` method to also do the same thing? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your mean calculation is wrong in the filled example, (you use axis=0 instead of 1). If I use the `fill_values` from the first example it looks okay,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [np.nan, 1,2], 
                                  'B' : [3, np.nan, 4], 
                                  'C': [5,6,np.nan]}).T
mask = np.isnan(df)
masked_df = np.ma.masked_array(df, mask)
fill_value = pd.DataFrame({col: df.mean(axis=1) for col in df.columns})
df = masked_df.filled(fill_value)
print(df)
```

outputs:

```
[[ 1.5  1.   2. ]
 [ 3.   3.5  4. ]
 [ 5.   6.   5.5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works, you can calculate the row-wise mean and pass this as the values to replace the `NaN` values, you have to transpose the mean so that the alignment is correctly performed:

```
In [154]:
df.fillna(df.mean(axis=1).T, axis=0)

Out[154]:
     0    1    2
A  1.5  1.0  2.0
B  3.0  3.5  4.0
C  5.0  6.0  5.5
```